# Degeneration of spectral sequence computing Hochschild cohomology of enveloping algebra of Lie algebroid

Tags: lie-algebra-cohomology, poisson-geometry, hochschild-cohomology, lie-groupoids

Let $L$ be a Lie algebroid on a smooth affine $k$-scheme $X=spec(R)$. Recall that by definition $L$ is a locally free sheaf with the structure of a sheaf of $k$ Lie algebras, so that there exists a linear map $\rho$, referred to as the *anchor* map, satisfying $$[\,fl_{1},l_{2}\,]=f[\,l_{1},l_{2}\,]+\rho(l_{2})(f)l_{1}.$$

Note that there is an associated $k$ Lie algebra structure on $R\oplus L$, with bracket $[\,(r,l),(r',l')\,]=(\rho(l')(r)+\rho(l)(r'),[\,l,l'\,]).$ Taking the quotient of the universal enveloping algebra of this $k$-algebra by the relations $r*l=(rl)$ we obtain the *universal enveloping algebra*, $U_{R}L$, of the Lie algebroid.

This is a filtered algebra and the associated graded is $Sym_{R}(L)$, which inherits thus a Poisson structure of weight $-1$ with respect to the grading on $Sym$. The associated spectral sequence converging to the Hochschild cohomology of $U_{R}L$ thus has $E^{1}$ page given by the Poisson cohomology $H^{*}_{\pi}(Sym_{R}L)$.

**Question.** Is it known that this spectral sequence degenerates at the $E^{1}$-page?

I imagine something like this should be extractable from Kontsevich's formality theorem but I am uncertain, especially as the above does not involve perturbative expansions, and I understand Kontsevich's results to apply only for a version of $U_{R}L$ with the relations deformed by a formal parameter $\hbar$.

P.S. Perhaps it would be good to add a *Lie Algebroids* tag.